# Two threads transferring data in both ways between two LinkedConcurrentQueue results in one empty queue while another "steals" everything

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

Everyone!

I've wrote a class (`InAndOut`) that extends `Thread`. This class receives in the constructor two `LinkedConcurrentQueue`, `entrance` and `exit`, and my `run` method transfers the objets from `entrance` to `exit`.

In my main method, I've instanciate two `LinkedConcurrentQueue`, `myQueue1` and `myQueue2`, with some values in each. Then, I've instanciate two InAndOut, one receiving `myQueue1` (entrance) and `myQueue2` (exit) and another receiving `myQueue2` (entrance) and `myQueue1` (exit). Then, I call the start method of both instances.

The result, after some iterations, is the transference of all objects from a queue to another, in other words, `myQueue1` becomes empty and `myQueue2` "steals" all the objects. But, if I add a sleep call in each iteration (something like 100 ms), then the behavior is like I've expected (equilibrium between element number in both queues).

Why it's happening and how to fix it? There are some way to do not use this sleep call in my run method? Am I doing something wrong?

Here is my source code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;

class InAndOut extends Thread {

    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> entrance;
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> exit;
    String name;

    public InAndOut(String name, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> entrance, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> exit){
        this.entrance = entrance;
        this.exit = exit;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void run() {
        int it = 0;
        while(it < 3000){
            String value = entrance.poll();

            if(value != null){
                exit.offer(value);
                System.err.println(this.name + " / entrance: " + entrance.size() + " / exit: " + exit.size());
            }

            //THIS IS THE SLEEP CALL THAT MAKES THE CODE WORK AS EXPECTED
            try{
                this.sleep(100);
            } catch (Exception ex){

            }
            it++;
        }
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> myQueue1 = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String>();
        ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> myQueue2 = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String>();

        myQueue1.offer("a");
        myQueue1.offer("b");
        myQueue1.offer("c");
        myQueue1.offer("d");
        myQueue1.offer("e");
        myQueue1.offer("f");
        myQueue1.offer("g");
        myQueue1.offer("h");
        myQueue1.offer("i");
        myQueue1.offer("j");
        myQueue1.offer("k");
        myQueue1.offer("l");

        myQueue2.offer("m");
        myQueue2.offer("n");
        myQueue2.offer("o");
        myQueue2.offer("p");
        myQueue2.offer("q");
        myQueue2.offer("r");
        myQueue2.offer("s");
        myQueue2.offer("t");
        myQueue2.offer("u");
        myQueue2.offer("v");
        myQueue2.offer("w");

        InAndOut es = new InAndOut("First", myQueue1, myQueue2);
        InAndOut es2 = new InAndOut("Second", myQueue2, myQueue1);

        es.start();
        es2.start();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what makes you think that the results should be balanced?  multi-threading is non-deterministic.

Comment: But the problem is, after some iterations, everything goes to one queue and never leave it. MyQueue2 takes everything and MyQueue1 becomes empty, the objects never come back. If I put the thread.Sleep, the behavior is non-deterministic, but makes more sense since the "emptiness" is a rare state and, when occurs, in following iterations, there are some objects back (even if it is only one object).

Comment: each thread only runs 3000 times and stops.  once the thread stops, nothing will leave that queue.  also, once a thread hits the empty state, it probably runs faster since it does no work.

Comment: Yeah, I know... because the thread ends. But if I increase the iteration number to 30000, the same problem occurs. If I put to print when it's trying to read an empty queue ("value == null"), I've got a lot of "First / entrance: 0 / exit: 23" and the second thread rarely appears and when it happens, the print is "Second/ entrance: 0 / exit: 23".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of execution with threads is undefined, so anything could happen. However since you do not start both threads simultaneously, you can make some assumptions on what might happen:

1. es is started first, so given a fast enough CPU, it has already pushed everything from queue1 into queue2 before the start of es2, then goes to sleep on take.
2. es2 starts and puts 1 element from queue2 back to queue1.
3. es wakes up at the same time and puts the element back.

Since both threads should "about" work at the same speed, one likely result is that there is only 1 or no element in `es` and all the remaining one in `es2`.

Comment: Well, in short, if a thread is started first, it will take everything, right? There are some way to eliminate this behavior? Or, make both threads to work simultaneously? I don't want all my objects in one queue... I want some balance between both queues

Comment: To be correct: it is possible that this happens and likely, but not guaranteed. If you want to start both at the exact same time, you need to synchronize them, i.E. by using a CyclicBarrier. But then still there is no guarantee whether or not those threads will balance the queues, because: __The order of execution with threads is undefined__

Comment: Yeah, after maturing everything, I think that I should use a solution that not work with threads, since the usage of both queues should work more or less synchronously. Another way to solve what I've in mind is to move the loop outside the thread and the loop starts and stops the thread with each iteration, to make use of all the cores of the machine. But may I control a loop using the result of the thread? I.E, call start and wait the result of both threads before the next iteration?

Answer (score 1):

Even if thread scheduling was deterministic the observed behavior remained plausible. As long as both threads perform the same task they might run balanced though you cannot rely on. But as soon as one queue runs empty the tasks are not balanced anymore. Compare:

1. Thread one polls from a queue which has items. The `poll` method will modify the source queue's state to reflect the removal, your code inserts the received item into the other queue, creating an internal list node object and modifying the target queue’s state to reflect the insertion. All modifications are performed in a way visible to other threads.
2. Thread two polls from an empty queue. The `poll` method checks a reference and finds `null` and that’s all. No other action is performed.

I think it should be obvious that one thread has far more to do than the other once one queue went empty. More precisely, one thread can finish its 3000 loop iterations (it could even do 300000) in a time that is not enough for the other to perform even a single iteration.

So once one queue is empty, one thread finishes its loop almost immediately and after that the other thread will transfer all items from one queue to the other and finish afterwards too.

So even with an almost deterministic scheduling behavior the balance would always bear the risk of tilting once one queue happens to get empty.

---

You can raise the chance for a balanced run by adding far more items to the queue to reduce the likelihood of one queue running empty. You can raise the number of iterations (to far bigger than a million) to avoid a thread exiting immediately when the queue runs empty or increment the counter only if a non-`null` item has been seen. You can use a [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) to let both threads wait before entering the loop compensating the thread startup overhead to have them run as synchronous as possible.

---

However, keep in mind that it still remains non-deterministic and polling loops waste CPU resources. Bot it’s ok to try and learn.

Answer (score 0):

jtahlborn is exactly right when he says that multithreading is non-deterministic and as such I would suggest you read more into what your expectations are in this application because it isn't quite clear and it is functioning as I would expect it (based on how it's coded).

With that said, you may be looking for a BlockingQueue and not a ConcurrentLinkedQueue.  A blocking queue will suspend the thread if empty and wait for it to have an items in it before continuing.  Swap out ConcurrentLinkedQueue with LinkedBlockingQueue.

The difference between the two is that if ConcurrentLinkedQueue doesn't have an item it will return quickly with a `null` value so it can finish through the 3000 iterations very very quickly.